# IE DIV with absolute positioning width goes to 100% of screen when it has a floating element inside

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have created a dialog box
( a div with position:absolute)
 if any element inside the box has a float : right 
the width of the box goes to 100% of the screen in IE7

float :left does not affect it.
this problem is specific to ie7

thank you for your help

Comment: What is the question you are asking?

Comment: This could be related to this difficult problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852104/internet-explorer-6-and-7-floated-elements-expand-to-100-width-when-they-contai

Comment: I guess there does not seem to be a non javascript solution.
@chris_I thank for the link

Comment: To bypass the float, you might be able to hack a solution together using a table with two cells & text-align. The two cells represent two floats next to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You absolutely have to set the width of an absolutely positioned element if it contains an element floated right to get it to behave properly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `float:right;` on the inner block, you can use `text-align:right;` on the parent block. See example:

```
<div style="position:absolute; text-align:right;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        123
    </div>
    <div>
        456
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/XLnYJ/49/

Tested on: ie 6 & 7; firefox; opera; gchrome.