# DIV in IE7 ,somehow ignores the width occupies the remaining space

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-7

Let me make it quick for you all :

Go to http://chetanreddy.com/chat/ in Internet Explorer 7.

Notice there is a lot of space after the single word.
Works fine in all except IE7.
Would appreciate your help.

If you want to edit it : http://jsbin.com/eribuf/3/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for starters you need a min-height on one of the background boxes, because it's breaking your gradient:

```
.wBoxTall .right, .gBoxTall .right {min-height: 29px;}
.wBoxTall .bottom .right, .gBoxTall .bottom .right {min-height: 0;}
```

Whenever you have issues in IE7, the first thing you should try is giving the element hasLayout - it's a weird little bug that means sometimes your styles don't work as they should. It's also often useful to specify a positioning. Try this:

```
.wBoxTall, .gBoxTall {zoom:1; position:relative}
```

Comment: min-height supported by IE versions below 9?

Comment: min-height is only supported by IE8+, but that's no reason not to include it in your CSS for all the other browsers. however, there are ways to make this work with IE7 and below - if you're keen on further solutions let me know.

Comment: @asprin: Yes IE lte 9 versions dont support this problem.

Comment: @zenkaty : Hey thanks for the reply ... Yes i know its breaking up my gradient,I will fix that, hey but the fix which you have given hasn't worked , could please elaborate, i just need it to work in ie7 and ie 8 !! Would largely appreciate your help!

Comment: I found another person having a similar problem, does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852104/internet-explorer-6-and-7-floated-elements-expand-to-100-width-when-they-conta

Comment: Hey @zenkaty tried that it definitely looks like like a haslayout problem ,the empty space is different in ie 7 and ie 8 , but no matter what i seem to be missing something,could you please help me ........ http://chetanreddy.com/chat/ i have uploaded it here ... look into it in IE 7.Thanks in advance

Comment: @zenkaty: 

in Firefox & other browsers: http://chetanreddy.com/chat/ff.png

in IE7,http://chetanreddy.com/chat/ie.png

Comment: Did you try the solution in the thread I linked to, with inline-block and text-align?

Comment: @zenkaty: yes i did i tried out almost every trick in http://haslayout.net/ & followed your advice too , one ie hack thought worked in occupying the white space in the div i.e., height : 1%, it reduced the white space in p element but fails to reduce the whitespace in the .bottom div, any tips will help from you !!!

Comment: Ok, I started again... this is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wFrZr/ - the width is working, just gotta get the bottom half the boxes working. I need to stop and do some actual work, so you want to have a go at the rest? I'll check up on you later :)